# How to get Page Meta by URL on Content Delivery?

Tags: content-delivery

I am having issues when trying to get the `PageMeta` from the page directly. Below is my sample code. Can you please advice me if I am doing it wrong?

> Error Message: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index at `IPageMeta pageMeta = (IPageMeta)result[0];`

```
/*
Use PageMetaFactory and retrieve the metadata of the page located at
/us/potential-at-work/application-leaders/article.aspx
*/
string pubID = "tcm:0-12-1";
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;

PageMetaFactory pageMetaFactory = new PageMetaFactory(pubID);      

IList result = pageMetaFactory.GetMetaByUrl(url);
IPageMeta pageMeta = (IPageMeta)result[0];
```

Answer (score 7):

As you state in your code comment, you need to pass in only the path of the URL (i.e. `/us/potential-at-work/application-leaders/article.aspx`). The problem is that you are using `AbsoluteUri`, which returns the entire URL as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.absoluteuri(v=vs.110).aspx. As such `pageMetaFactory.GetMetaByUrl(url)` returns an empty collection and you try reading the first element. Hence, the index our of range.

You should be using `AbsolutePath` as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.absolutepath(v=vs.110).aspx.

I suggest also you check what is the actual URL of the page, either by looking it up in the Content Delivery DB, table `PAGE`, column `URL`, or on the Content Manager side, object `Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.Page`, property `PublishLocationUrl`.

Comment: Thank u Mihai. It is working now.

Comment: Once I get the Page meta (metadata filled being Category and Keyword field), is it possible to get the TCM URI of the Keyword and then get the metadata filled values of the Keyword?

`String editionVal = compCustomMeta.GetValue("edition");`